Morphisms on L^2(G) induced by morphisms of LCA groups
I am looking for a good reference to understand the space $L^2(G)$ for a locally compact abelian (LCA) group $G$.
In particular, I would like to understand when $L^2(-)$ is functorial, so that if $\phi:G\rightarrow H$ is a morphism of LCA groups, the induced "pullback" map
\begin{align*}
\phi^*:L^2(H) \rightarrow L^2(G); \quad \eta \mapsto \eta \circ \phi 
\end{align*}
preserves the property of being $L^2$ (this all in the hopes of eventually gaining a better understanding automorphic forms, using Abelian groups as a warm up). Does anyone know of such a reference? As well as a good example of when such a construction fails? Thank you so much!

I understand how questions like this could arise for automorphic forms, but with abelian groups? (As to the question itself, if $\phi$ is proper, then it carries $C_c(H)$ to $C_c(G)$, and that might be enough for some purposes.  My intuition is that there won't be good general conditions, but I don't know.)

Thank you @LSpice! Yes, I am looking to Abelian groups as a warm up before diving into automorphic forms themselves. I have updated the post appropriately.

Your formulation is weird, since you write the map as $L^2(H)\to L^2(G)$ and then ask when it maps into $L^2(G)$. First, for the map to be well-defined at the level of classes of maps (i.e., has the property that two functions that coincide a.e. are mapped to functions that coincide a.e.) is true iff the map $G\to H$ is open. [I'm assuming groups are second-countable.] Then it maps $L^2$ into $L^2$ iff $H\to G$ has compact kernel.

@YCor That's amazing! Do you happen to know where I could look for a reference for the compact kernel part? Also you are right, the mapping was meant to be $\eta \mapsto \phi \circ \eta$, I have ammended the question appropriately.

There is a homomorphism from G to the trivial group but this does not give a bounded linear map from $L^2(G)$ to the complex numbers; there is a homomorphism from the trivial group to the real numbers but no functorial way to make this into a linear map from the complex numbers to $L^2({\bf R})$. So I think that the question needs to be rethought: there are much more basic isssues that need to be resolved before one starts considering Fourier analysis or automorphic forms or anything fancy
